# Escape sequences like [<8;38;34m being inserted into my document when I middle click

Tags: terminal-emacs, ansi

I recently updated to emacs 25.1, and I'm noticing that sometimes escape sequences like `[<8;38;34m` or `[<8;20;27m` are being inserted into my document. I use emacs in the terminal (`emacs -nw`). I use iTerm2 on macOS.

I haven't yet figured out what I do when this happens (I have thus far only noticed it after it happened). If I do I'll post more here.

Can any shed some light on what might be causing this? I can't figure out what ANSI escape sequence this might be. I haven't found a great list of sequences, but none of the ones I've seen have anything close to this.

Comment: This is an escape sequence that the terminal sends to report mouse events. See [ctlseqs](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Extended-coordinates), the SGR variant. CSI is `ESC [`. It appears that the terminal is sending these escape sequences but Emacs doesn't support them. Are you running Emacs from some other program in the same terminal that might have activated mouse reporting? Can you reproduce this with `emacs -q` (and if not post a `.emacs` that reproduces the problem)? With `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Well so far I can't figure out how to reproduce it at all, but once I do I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like emacs 28.1 has fixed whatever was causing this. Quite a few things relating to terminal mouse reporting are much better in emacs 28.1.